# ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

This question might have asked here number of times . After doing some google search for the above error and doing some update, I can't understand why I'm still getting that error. I've already put my driver-- mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin in the classpath:

```
Java_Home\jre\lib\
Java_Home\jre\lib\ext\
Java_Home\lib
```

and the code which I'm using to connect to mysql database is:

```
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mail","root","");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select message_body from deadletter");
String dbtime;
while (rs.next()) {
dbtime = rs.getString(1);
System.out.println(dbtime);
} 

con.close();

}
catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and the complete stacktrace of the above exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc:Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at mail.main(mail.java:114)
```

Now, what's wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: So, what exactly does your classpath look like? You must put the JAR file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar) in the classpath.

Comment: The exception message has a colon in the class name, which I don't believe should happen.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line has been obsolete since JDBC 4 in 2007, and whatever MySQL Connector first implemented it.

Comment: Ran into this in a Spring Boot project and resolved by including this in the Gradle dependencies block:
```runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most common cause is that you have some conflict in where your classes are loaded from. For example if you have 2 locations and one has JDBC drivers and the other one not then if your classloader loads from the 1st location and some class from the 1st location wants to use the driver - the driver is not there. So look for the duplicate JARs that are using your driver

Comment: @Bostone I thought that the driver went with [Apache James itself](http://wiki.apache.org/james/V3ConfigTutorial).

Answer (score 42):

If you're facing this problem with Eclipse, I've been following many different solutions but the one that worked for me is this:

1. Right click your project folder and open up Properties.
2. From the right panel, select Java Build Path then go to Libraries tab.
3. Select Add External JARs to import the mysql driver.
4. From the right panel, select Deployment Assembly.
5. Select Add..., then select Java Build Path Entries and click Next.
6. You should see the sql driver on the list. Select it and click first.

And that's it! Try to run it again! Cheers!

Comment: You saved my day man (actually a week!). Of all the solutions on the internet this was the one I needed. Strange ways of eclipse :->

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I struggled with this problem for over 2 hours, and this was the solution to the problem. A sincere thank you!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me as well. Specifically, steps 4-6 are the additional steps that resolved the database connectivity issue I was facing.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe that after 2.5 years, my solution is still working for you guys. Code on!

Answer (score 27):

I too struggled with the same problem and finally got the solution for it.
Just copy the `MySql-Connector.jar` into Tomcat's `lib` folder, and then remove the jar from the webapp's `lib` folder, and then, run the project.

Comment: This works . Yet this is not a good solution I guess. Can you suggest a more formal way

Comment: If you are using any IDE then the "Server Clean" will do this task. If you are not using IDE then you have to do this manually.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem
but I found this after a long search:
http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-JDBC-Driver-Load-Class.html

But I made some change. I put the driver in the same folder as my `ConTest.java` file, 
and compile it, resulting in `ConTest.class`.

So in this folder have

```
ConTest.class
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar
```

and I write this

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar ConTest
```

This way if you not use any IDE just cmd in windows or shell in linux.

Comment: For linux, you would have to replace ' ; ' with ' : '

Comment: work for me! thank you so much, you guys save my weekend!

Comment: Are you sure this works? It gives that the term mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar is not recognized as the name of cmdlet.

Answer (score 6):

this ans is for eclipse user......

first u check the jdbc jar file is add in Ear libraries....

if yes...then
check...in web Content->web Inf folder->lib

and past here jdbc jar file in lib folder.....

Comment: Solved my problem in 2020 :=)... Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

1) Download connector from here https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

2) Select JDBC driver for mysql

3) click on Platform Independent (Architecture Independent), ZIP Archive

4) Download the file and unzip it

5) (For Eclipse)Click Project->properties-> Java Build Path->Libraries
(For Netbeans) right click libraries on left bar-> add jar

6) Click on add external jar

7) select mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

8) Done!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using NetBeans follow the following steps:

1. Right click on 'Libraries' and select 'Add Library..'
2. Scroll down the list of 'Global Libraries' and select 'MySQL JDBC Driver' and click on 'Add Library'.

Answer (score 3):

What did you put exactly in `lib`, `jre/lib` or `jre/lib/ext`? Was it the jar `mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar` or something else (like a directory)?

By the way, I wouldn't put it in `lib`, `jre/lib` or `jre/lib/ext`, there are other ways to add a jar to the classpath. You can do that by adding it explicitly the CLASSPATH environment variable. Or you can use the `-cp` option of `java`. But this is another story.

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans,

1. right click on libraries, select `properties`
2. select `rub` tab
3. there you need to add the `mysql-connector-java.jar` and apply

Answer (score 2):

You should download [MariaDB connector](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/connector-java-2.0.2/mariadb-java-client-2.0.2.jar).
Then:

1. Expand your project.
2. Right-click on `Libraries`.
3. Select `Add Jar/Folder`.
4. Add `mariadb-java-client-2.0.2.jar` which you just downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i find solution changing the path of mysql-conector-java.jar to the follow path:

```
ProjectName/WebContent/Web-inf/lib/mysql-conector-java.jar
```

So you need to add the conector to project again and delete the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the possible solution has been covered above. From my experience of this issue, i have placed the mysql-connector-jar in the /WEB-INF/lib folder of the webapp module and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In netbean
Right click on your project, then you click on Libraries,  then Run tab, add  library, then select mysql connector

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ 
Do as they say in eclipse 
"If you're facing this problem with Eclipse, I've been following many different solutions but the one that worked for me is this:

Right click your project folder and open up Properties.

From the right panel, select Java Build Path then go to Libraries tab.

Select Add External JARs to import the mysql driver.

From the right panel, select Deployment Assembly.

Select Add..., then select Java Build Path Entries and click Next.

You should see the sql driver on the list. Select it and click first.

And that's it! Try to run it again! Cheers!"

Here we have to add the jar file in Project Structure -> Libraries -> +(add)

Answer (score 0):

I keep the mysql-connector jar with my project rather than in Javahome. As a result, you can be sure it can be found by being sure its in the local classpath. A big upside is that you you can more the project to another machine and not have to worry about (or forget) to set this up again. I personally like including it in version control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..May be i  can also contribute my solution..
Right click on project -properties -->Deployment assembly...there you need to add the mysql-connector-java.jar and apply it...which makes your prject configured with web-Libraries that has this sql connector...This worked for me..
I hope this works for you guys as well

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was downloading the **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** directly from the MySQL website:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Then if you're using Eclipse paste this **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar**  in the WEB-INF lib folder

If doesn't works try with any of the solutions posted in this link:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/jdbc-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error after upgrading my java to 1.8.0_101. Try this:
i. Remove the mysql.jar fro your buildpath.
ii. Clean the server and project
iii. Add the jar file back to the build path.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the MySQL JDBC drive jar file and paste it to Tomcat or whatever is the server's lib folder. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste the mysqlconnector jar to your project folder and then build path it will definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

see to it that the argument of Class. forName method is exactly "com. mysql. jdbc. Driver".
If yes then see to it that mysql connector is present in lib folder of the project. if yes then see to it that the same mysql connector . jar file is in the ClassPath variable (system variable)..

Comment: No spaces: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"