# How to install JDBC driver in servlet based project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundexception

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

[There is a VERY similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver) to mine but in my case I don't have any duplicate jars in my build path, so the solution does not work for me.  I've searched google for a couple of hours now, but none of the solutions I've found there actually resolve my issue.  I'm creating a web site with some database connectivity for a homework.  I'm using a MySQL database, developing in Eclipse and running on Windows.

I keep getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;
//...
public void someMethodInMyServlet(PrintWriter out)
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    try {

        out.println("Create the driver instance.<br>");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        out.println("Get the connection.<br>");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "secret");
        query = connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM customers");

        //...
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e.toString()+"<br>");
    }
}
//...
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:

```
Create the driver instance.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It doesn't get past the `Class.forName...` line and I can't figure out why! Here is what I did:

1. Download mysql-connector.
2. Put it in my MySQL folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar`.
3. Opened the project properties in Eclipse.
4. Add External Jar to my Build Path and I selected `mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar`.

Every time I attempt to use the servlet I get the same error regardless if I have the jar in there or if I don't. Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: What happens with a non-servlet test program on the command line? `java -cp C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar;...`

Comment: @trashgod I just made a dummy test project with an empty Main class: `..\Test\src>java -cp "C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-con
nector-java-5.1.12\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar"; Main.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/java`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As for every "3rd-party" library in flavor of a JAR file which is to be used by the webapp, just copy/drop the physical JAR file in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. It will then be available in webapp's default classpath. Also, Eclipse is smart enough to notice that. No need to hassle with buildpath. However, make sure to remove all unnecessary references you added before, else it might collide.

In case you're using Maven as dependency management tool, then it's sufficient to basically add Maven coordinates of the desired JDBC driver JAR file as a new `<dependency>` in project's `pom.xml`. It will eventually automatically end up in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. In case of the MySQL JDBC driver you can find the coordinates [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html).

An alternative is to install it in the server itself by dropping the physical JAR file in server's own `/lib` folder. This is required when you're using server-provided JDBC connection pool data source which in turn needs the MySQL JDBC driver. See also the following links.

#### See also:

- [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/when-and-where-to-add-jar-files-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnot)
- [How should I connect to JDBC database / datasource in a servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-from-eclipse/)
- [Where do I have to place the JDBC driver for Tomcat's connection pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161747/jdbc-apache-tomcat-pooling-jar)
- [JDBC CLASSPATH Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720284/jdbc-classpath-not-working/)

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and your solution worked. But what is the difference between adding a JAR file in webapp's '/WEB-INF/lib' and adding the same JAR file in buildpath? If every 3rd party library should be added in '/WEB-INF/lib', then why does buildpath have option for adding External JAR files?

Comment: @Hiral: that section in the project's *Build Path* is for compiletime classpath. To have the JAR to end up in runtime classpath as well, add it in project's  *Deployment Assembly* list as well. Note that this ultimately ends up as a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` when the WAR is been built/exported. So why not just drop it right there in first place?

Comment: THANK YOU so much.. i couldn't figure out why the same code was working in a java application but not in the servlet..Your answer works great :)

Comment: For anyone else new to Eclipse, you can add the jar into your project's Deployment Assembly by going to Properties > 'Deployment Assembly' > 'Add...' > 'Java Build Path Entries' and selecting your jar. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are running it in `servlet`, you need to have the jar accessible by the *servlet container*. You either include the connector as part of your application `war` or put it as part of the servlet container's extended library and datasource management stuff, if it has one. The second part is totally depend on the container that you have.

Comment: I'm running a Tomcat server through Eclipse... can you be more specific given that information? Where do I have to put the jar?

Comment: Place mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar to the \Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\lib folder

Answer (score 4):

The others are right about making the driver JAR available to your servlet container. My comment was meant to suggest that you verify from the command line whether the driver itself is intact.

Rather than an empty `main()`, try something like this, adapted from the included documentation:

```
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
}
```

On my platform, I'd do this:

```
$ ls mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar
$ javac LoadDriver.java 
$ java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar:. LoadDriver
```

On your platform, you need to use `;` as the path separator, as discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) and [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Answer (score 3):

Place mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar to the \Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\lib folder. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Only when the OP is using a container-managed `DataSource`, not when the OP is fiddling with `DriverManager` manually. For that placing JAR in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` as in my answer is more than sufficient.

Comment: I tried all the other, more elegant approaches - and failed. Brute force - placing it in the lib did - worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### What you should not do do (especially when working on a shared project)

Ok, after had the same issue and after reading some answers here and other places. it seems that putting `external lib` into `WEB-INF/lib` is not that good idea as it `pollute webapp/JRE libs with server-specific libraries` -  [for more information check this answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832841/1211174)

Another solution that i do NOT recommend is: **to copy it into tomcat/lib folder**. although this may work, it will be hard to manage dependency for a shared(git for example) project.

### Good solution 1

Create `vendor` folder. put there all your external lib. then, map this folder as dependency to your project. in eclipse you need to

1. add your folder to the **`build path`**

   1. `Project Properties` -> `Java build path`
   2. `Libraries` -> add external lib or any other solution to add your files/folder
2. add your build path to **`deployment Assembly`** ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467530/1211174))

   1. `Project Properties` -> `Deployment Assembly`
   2. `Add` -> `Java Build Path Entries`
   3. You should now see the list of libraries on your build path that you can       specify for inclusion into your finished WAR.
   4. Select the ones you want and hit Finish.

### Good solution 2

Use `maven` (or any alternative) to manage project dependency

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps:

1) Install eclipse
2) Import Apache to eclipse
3) Install mysql
4) Download mysqlconnector/J
5) Unzip the zipped file navigate through it until you get the bin file in it. Then place all files that are present in the folder containing bin to C:\Program Files\mysql\mysql server5.1/
then give the same path as the address while defining the driver in eclipse.

That's all very easy guys.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem still persists,

Put the-
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin jar in a place inside your Tomcat->lib->folder (No matter where you've installed your Tomcat). And change your environmental variable (Done by clicking Properties of Mycomputer -Advanced system settings- Environmental variables-And set a new variable name & variable values as the place where your lib file resides.Dont forget to enter a ; at the end of the path)

If still problem persists
Try downloading commons-collections-2.0.jar (http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/commons-collections-2.0.jar.html) and paste the jar in the same place where your mysql jar resides (ie) inside Tomcat-lib.

Clean your project-Stop your server- Finally try to run.

Answer (score 0):

Many times I have been facing this problem, I have experienced ClassNotFoundException.
if jar is not at physical location.

So make sure .jar file(mysql connector) in the physical location of WEB-INF lib folder. and
make sure restarting Tomcat by using shutdown command in cmd.
it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution worked for me is  putting the .jar file under WEB-INF/lib  . Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your project is maven based, add it to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Save > Build > and test connection again. It works! Your actual mysql java connector version may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Put mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar to the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib folder.by doing this program with execute

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a little different. Instead of `jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/service` i had it as `server:port/service`.

Missing was `jdbc:oracle:thin:@` in `url` attribute in GlobalNamingResources.Resource. But I overlooked tomcat exception's

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'server:port/service'
```

Answer (score -2):

for this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

you need to:

```
Import java.sql.*;
Import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
```

even if its not used till app running.