# JDBC CLASSPATH Not Working

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath

I'm setting up a simple JDBC connection to my working MySQL database on my server. I'm using the Connector-J provided by MySQL. According to their documentation, I'm suppose to create the CLASSPATH variable to point to the directory where the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar is located. I used `export set CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH`. When I type `echo $CLASSPATH` to see if it exists, everything seems fine. But then when I open a new terminal and type `echo $CLASSPATH` it's no longer there. I think this is the main reason why my Java server won't connect to the JDBC, because it isn't saving the CLASSPATH variable I set.

Anyone got suggestions or fixes on how to set up JDBC in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It's a big joke. It's ignored by pretty much everything else than a low-level `java com.example.Foo` command. It's ignored when you add the `-jar` argument. It's ignored when you add the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument. It's ignored by IDE's and web/application servers. That environment variable was intented as a convenience for starters. But beyond that, it's useless.

It boils down to that the JAR file has got to be placed in any of the existing/default paths of the runtime classpath of the Java application in question, or that at least the path to the JAR file is to be added to the runtime classpath of the Java application in question.

Since you're talking about a server and considering the fact that the `CLASSPATH` environment variable doesn't work, I'll assume that it's actually a webserver/appserver such as Apache Tomcat. If that's indeed true, you've got to either drop the JAR file in `Tomcat/lib` folder (if you use the container managed `DataSource` approach for a fast connection pool), or in webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` folder (if you use the poor man's `Class#forName()` approach to load the driver).

If it's not and it's actually a Java application which is to be executed as a JAR, then you've got to specify the classpath in `MANIFEST.MF` file of the JAR in question. But if it's also not that and it is a loose `.class` file, then you've got to specify the classpath in `-cp` or `-classpath` argument of `java` command. To save yourself from typing it again and again when executing it, just create a `.sh` file with the command.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

before getting your connection

You might also want to get a more recent version of the mysql jdbc driver. 5.0.8 is pretty old.

Take a look at [JDBC Basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) it will give you some tips.

This [tutorial](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3417381) might help you as well.

Comment: Actually, to be honest... let me give you some background. I actually just started a new server because my old server died of a hard drive failure. My old server was running JDBC just find on Debian Lenny. This new server, though, is running Debian Squeeze on an Atom processor, for now. Anyway, I've been having a harder time setting up JDBC on this machine but I do know that my Java server has worked so it's not a problem in the Java program.

Comment: Can you post some more information, such as the stack trace you get, and the command line you use to start the process? The output of java -version might be useful as well.

Comment: Sure, I'm using Java 1.5.0 according java -version. Here's the exact stack trace I'm getting when the server can't connect to the JDBC.

Comment: Sure, I'm using Java 1.5.0 according to java -version. Here's the stack trace:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????????????????????' at line 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)... blah blah blah

Comment: This step hasn't been necessary since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working on a linux box. Make sure that your terminal launches a `login` shell. For example the `gnome-terminal` application (probably what you are using if you are using a ubuntu or fedora box for development) has a checkbox under the profile preferences > Title and command menu called "run command as a login shell". Check that and make sure you also put this code in the ~/.bash_profile file at the end.

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

But i would argue against doing this and doing a simple launch script for your application. Something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Set CLASSPATH=CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH

java -cp "$CLASSPATH" <your.main.application.Class>
```

make executable and use that to launch your application.

Comment: check out what @Balusc said because is the same thing basically. Just make sure your application starts with the jdbc driver in it's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but it might help someone.

I have succeeded connecting to SQLite3 on Windows 7 with the proper CLASSPATH

I use the JDBC driver sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.

First I tried to copy the driver under the directory c:\Program Files\java\jre7\lib and then set the CLASSPATH variable, but that failed to recognize the line :

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

I think that's due to the Windows bug to have spaces in a folder name like "Program Files".

So I copied the JAR file under C:\jbmorla and set the CLASSPATH to:

```
.;c:\jbmorla\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For **MAVENS project** solution. You can directly modify the **pom.xml** file.
Add the mysql-connector dependency to the pom.xml project file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04: Set permanent class path of jdbc driver

Install Mariadb driver

```
sudo apt install libmariadb-java
```

Put the class path in `.bashrc` file

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Save the file