# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError on HttpServletRequest that is pointing to ServletFileUpload?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload, noclassdeffounderror

I recently started using JMeter to load test my webapp, locally on my pc. I have a jsp page for uploading images. The images are processed by my servlet. When I tried the process today, I got the following exception/error :

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.uploadEditedImagesToDB(ImageProcessingServlet.java:527)
    spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.doPost(ImageProcessingServlet.java:153)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Here is the code from my servlet that the exception is referring to -

```
boolean isPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
```

....and yes, I've put all the necessary `import` statements in the class.

I can't recall making any changes to anything on my system that would cause this problem. This process has always run without any problems, so I don't understand what is causing it to fail like this now. Its rather coincidental, I think, that it is failing after I've been using JMeter...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All 3rd party webapp libraries like Commons FileUpload belong in `/WEB-INF/lib` of your webapp, not elsewhere. This exception can occur whenever you've placed it in `JRE/lib` or `JRE/lib/ext`.

And indeed, as Bozho mentions, you need to ensure as well that you haven't moved/copied/duplicated any servletcontainer-specific libraries (which should be left untouched in `Tomcat/lib`) around in different places of the classpath. But that should IMO not have resulted in this kind of exception. It's basically telling that the classloader which loaded the FileUpload API has totally no knowledge about the Servlet API.

If you read the [Tomcat classloading HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), then you'll see that the libraries in `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext` are loaded by a different classloader (*bootstrap*) than the ones in `Tomcat/lib` (*common*) and `/WEB-INF/lib` (*webapp*). The bootstrap classloader has  no knowledge about common and webapp libraries. It's the other way round. The *common* classloader has knowledge about the *bootstrap* classloader and the *webapp* classloader has knowledge about both. Since the Servlet API is normally loaded by the *common* classloader, this can only mean that the FileUpload API was loaded by the *bootstrap* classloader. And this is wrong :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. I removed the 3rd party jars from the jre/lib/ext folder (I had copied them in there), and after a restart (not reinstall) of Tomcat, the process is back up and running as it was.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your servlet container does not have the servlet api. Take a clean installation of Tomcat and try to deploy there. First check that you have the servlet api jar in `tomcat/lib`. And make sure you don't have it in `webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Yes, the servlet-api.jar is in c:\jakarta-tomcat\lib only. I'm running Tomcat 6.0.29.

Comment: @katura - just try it on a fresh installation. Install = unzip.