# <error-page> tag in web.xml doesn't catch java.lang.Throwable Exceptions

Tags: servlets, web.xml, custom-error-pages

I have a web-app developed with servlet & JSP. I configured my app to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if I insert bad parameters.
Then I configured my web.xml file in this way:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

When I rise a `404 error`, then it works and calls `error.jsp`, but when I rise a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, then it does not work and I've a `blank page` instead of `error.jsp`. Why?

The server is Glassfish, and logs show really IllegalArgumentException rised.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe you are catching the IllegalArgumentException somewhere else in your code?

Comment: yes I catch the exception in a catch in the java code... it may be the problem?

Comment: If you already caught it in your code, then the server which called your code won't retrieve it. Simple as that. Just remove the catch and let it go, or rethrow the caught exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not catch and suppress it, but just let it go.

I.e. do not do:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        doSomethingWhichMayThrowException();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Or something else which totally suppresses the exception.
    }
}
```

But rather just let it go:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doSomethingWhichMayThrowException();
}
```

Or, if you actually intented to catch it for logging or so (I'd rather use a filter for that, but ala), then rethrow it:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        doSomethingWhichMayThrowException();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Or, if it's not an runtime exception, then rethrow it wrapped in `ServletException`, it will be automatically unwrapped by the container:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        doSomethingWhichMayThrowException();
    } catch (NotARuntimeException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [How does server prioritize which type of web.xml error page to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299169/how-does-tomcat-prioritize-which-type-of-error-page-to-use/)
- [Submitting form to Servlet which interacts with database results in blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044204/submitting-form-to-servlet-which-interacts-with-database-results-in-blank-page)

Comment: After I  mapped a servlet for  exception handling  in web.xml and I want to prevent to print the socket excpetion stackTrace  on Jboss console. wrote in do post of mapped servlet like ` Object attribute = req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
   if(attribute instanceof  SocketException){` ,Still the stackTrace  printing on the jboss and then this servlet triggering.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Another (simplified) approach is not to declare multiple handlers for various `<error-code>` and `<exception-type>` situations but rather have one, sort of catch-all sink, e.g.

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error-page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Inside your `error-page.jsp` you can determine the cause, be it a return status code or an exception as described here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm These constants are a part of the standard [Servlet 3.0 API](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html).

For instance a primitive `error-page.jsp` response handler placed into the root of your webapp can look like this:

```
Server encountered a situation
Status code: <%=(Integer) request.getAttribute(javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE)%>
<br>
Exception: <%=(Throwable) request.getAttribute(javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION)%>
```

For security reasons I wouldn't recommend sending the exact exception type to the client; this is just an example of how to handle different types of errors and response statuses inside a `JSP` handler; a servlet can be used instead of JSP.

One common catch-all handler vs one per status code is certainly dependent on the situation and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have today the same issue. (JavaEE 7 and Glassfish 4.0)

The problem seems that the framework check it as String instead with the Class.

#### String based check (the hypothesis)

When a Exception is twrown, `e.getClass()` is compared with `<exception-type>` as string.
So you can't use inheritance.

Note that nested classes must be pointed as '$' instead '.' (same as getClass() method).

#### Class based check

The framework create an instance of the class, and `<exception-type>` text refer to it, and the `class.isInstance()` is used to check.

This will need reflection and policy file could break it.

I hope that this response solves future issues.