# Tomcat doesnt use my Error-Page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to handle runtime exceptions and all other exceptions in a single exception handler on my Tomcat Server.

If i write in my web.xml File:

```
  <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/Exceptionhandler</location>
</error-page>
```

It works perfectly fine, but if i write

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/Exceptionhandler</location>
</error-page>
```

It doens't use my own Exceptionhandler. Instead it throws the usual Error-Page from Tomcat.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965869/error-page-tag-in-web-xml-doesnt-catch-java-lang-throwable-exceptions)

Comment: Here is an interesting link on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965869/error-page-tag-in-web-xml-doesnt-catch-java-lang-throwable-exceptions Maybe it's related to your problem

Comment: thanks that helped :)