# failed to develop login page with ajax

Tags: javascript, sql, json, ajax, servlets

I have been trying to develop a login page using ajax and servlet. But I haven't successfully created one. The results are always different from what I expected. I even tried referring to a previously successful file but I still failed.

These are my codes:

1. index.html

```
 <form id="loginFrm">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                </div>

                <div class="container">

                    <input type="radio" value="Urusetia" name="loginRole">Urusetia<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="Penyelaras PITA" name="loginRole">Penyelaras PITA<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="Penyelia" name="loginRole">Penyelia<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="Penilai" name="loginRole">Penilai<br>
                    <input type="radio" value="Pelajar" name="loginRole">Pelajar<br>

                    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" required>

                    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" required>

                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

2. index.js

```
$(function(){
$("#loginFrm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();



        var datalist = "username="+username+"&password="+password;


        $.ajax({
           type:"post", 
           url:"LogMasuk",
           data:datalist,
           cache: false,
           success: function(mydata){

               var myData = JSON.parse(mydata);
               if(myData.status === 1){
                   alert("Success");
                   sessionStorage.token = username;
                   location.href = "dashboard.html";
               }else if(myData.status === 0){
                   alert("User not found.");
               }
           },
           error: function(){
               console.log("AJAX error.");
           }
        });
    });
});
```

3. LogMasuk.java

```
public class LogMasuk extends HttpServlet {
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

     JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     try {
         /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
         String username = request.getParameter("username");
         String password = request.getParameter("password");

         jo = dbAPI.LogMasuk(username, password);

     } finally {
         out.print(jo);
         out.close();
     }
 }
```

and the file to refer to database

```
public static JSONObject LogMasuk(String username, String password){
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        boolean exist = false;

        try{
            con = conMan.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM pelajar WHERE username=? AND password=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                exist = true;
            }
            if(exist){
                jo.put("status", 1);
            }
            else
                jo.put("status", 0);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            jo.put("status", -1);
        }
        return jo;
```

Every time I always hit {} response in the browser's console under the network tab even the status code is ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in index.js `$("#function(){` should be `$(function(){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by bad exception handling.

Your code threw an exception, most likely a `ClassNotFoundException` on the JDBC driver, but you're basically completely suppressing it by forcing the close of the response body in the `finally` block.

```
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    out.print(jo);
    out.close(); // BAD! Remove this line!
}
```

This way you're basically preventing the server from showing its default error response which usually contains a stack trace and thus effectively the answer to your real problem.

Better yet, do not handle exceptions like that in a servlet. Remove the `try-finally` block altogether.

```
// ...
out.print(jo);
```

If any, you should be rethrowing any checked exception as a `ServletException` in a `catch` block.

```
try {
    // ...
    out.print(jo);
} catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

This way the server will be able to properly deal with it and you can configure the error response body in `web.xml`.

#### See also:

- [Submitting form to Servlet which interacts with database results in blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044204/submitting-form-to-servlet-which-interacts-with-database-results-in-blank-page)
- [How should I connect to JDBC database / datasource in a servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-jdbc-database-datasource-in-a-servlet-based-applicatio)
- [How to install JDBC driver in Eclipse web project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/how-to-install-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse-web-project-without-facing-java-lang-class)