# MySQL jdbc driver and Eclipse problems

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am having problems loading the MySQL JDBC driver. I have tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver), but am still running into problems.

The error I get is this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      //accessing the driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");

      // creating variable to pass the connection information into
      Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");

      PreparedStatement statement = dbcon
            .prepareStatement("select * from names");

      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

      while (result.next()) {
         System.out.println(result.getString(2));

      }
   }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see above I have placed the driver in the `lib` folder and I have also put it into the Apache tomcat lib folder, because that was suggested as well.

Thank you for any help you can give me.
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you the problem on the first line of your stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

The driver name is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (capital D).

Comment: thankyou i feel like a fool now, i knew the probelm was in the main but no idea it needed to be capital, iam sorry for such a simple question

Comment: Oh, this happens to everyone trust me. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

The class name inside the MySql connectorJ JAR file is Driver. so you need to change

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score 0):

problem in loading the mysql connection library.please check the proper mysql library is load successfully.because when library load successfully then the library package display all the external loaded library.