# jdbc type 4 -java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Hi I am beginner in java and I have created a java program in eclipse using jdbc type 4.

I got an error :
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

so can you please help me in resolving this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi thanks but how do i set classpath ?

Comment: Read the answer of @BaluSc : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You need [MySQL Connector jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) which is not in classpath. Add it in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1) Run java app with classpath

Windows

```
java -classpath .;mysqljarfile.jar YourApplication
```

Linux

```
java -classpath .:mysqljarfile.jar YourApplication
```

2) Define it in your manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: mysqljarfile.jar 
Main-Class: mainClass
```

Comment: I misread. In eclipse you can add library in Properties/JavaBuildPath

Comment: I have been creating this program using eclipse so how do i set the class path  in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your mysql connector jar file to your project WEB-INF\lib folder and redeploy again.

Comment: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306? i tried adding the jar file and now