# MySQL jdbc driver ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, exception, servlets, jdbc

After googling a lot and seeing the answers here on SO of similar questions, I am still getting this error of ClassNotFoundException.

I tried the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-eclipse-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver).

My apache tomcat webapps directory is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps`. I also uploaded the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` file in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib` as mentioned in some of answers here in SO.

In my webapps/jsp folder I created an index.jsp file but it shows an error in the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

My current folder structure is:

```
     C:\
        -> Program Files
            -> Apache Software Foundation 
                ->  Tomcat 6.0
                    -> webapps
                         -> jsp
                             -> index.jsp
                             -> WEB-INF
                                 ->  lib
                                     -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: jars from `jre/lib/ext` (not `jre/lib`) get into classpath automatically, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov well, I had copied the jar file in both the folders /lib and /lib/ext

Comment: Do not modify the jre libraries because sooner or later you will end with compatibility issues; add the libraries to your webapp libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all of your libraries under this kind of structure :

```
  C:\
    -> Program Files
        -> Apache Software Foundation 
            ->  Tomcat 6.0
                -> webapps
                     -> Your web application
                         -> WEB-INF
                             ->  lib
                                 -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar (and all other required jars)
```

You should include all your libraries inside the `lib` folder as any classes that your web app requires will be available to it readily from there.

This what [servletworld.com](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/web-application-directory-structure.html) says
*"... classes and resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib directory are included in classpath and made visible to the containing web application."*

Comment: Still, not working. When I run `localhost:8080/jsp` in my browser, I still get the same error!

Comment: @Abu: I added my directory structure in my question above, check it

Comment: @Yevgeniy I added some explanation

Answer (score -1):

You can include the mysql jar file in the web application itself.
Include the jar in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar

Comment: yep, had seen this somewhere. But there is **NO** WEB_INF folder in my webapps. I even tried creating one, but still no effect.

Comment: Then you must create one...

Comment: It is not WEB_INF. It is WEB-INF(hyphen). Try with it

Comment: yup, actually my mistake. I had tried with WEB-INF.