# ClassNotFound for Mysql connectivity in JavaEE application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I've added mysql connector jar file, but class not found exception still arises.

[image: image of added libraries]*

Comment: Check you have added the jar in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Good practice at SO is giving exception as text, not image

Comment: A tip for asking questions: copy the text of the stack trace and include it directly in the question. It is much much easier to read that way, and in addition will actually work for other people searching for it. Don't take a picture of the text : ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MySQL JDBC driver in Eclipse web project without java.lang.ClassNotFoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/how-to-install-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse-web-project-without-java-lang-classn)

Answer (score 2):

Your error clearly says that the `MySql` connector jar is not placed in the correct folder. The correct folder is `WEB-INF/lib`. So place your jar in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have your eclipse project referencing the mysql library.  This allows the compiler, in eclipse, to find the classes when compiling.  However, you do not have the library as part of your web app when you publish it to your tomcat server.  You need to remove the library from the project, and copy the jar file into your app's `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.classnotfoundexception` `com.mysql.jdbc.MySql` issued by `WebAppClassLoader`. This tells that you need to include `MySql` connector jar in your web path under `WEB-INF/lib` directory.