java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver in HttpServlet
There is an error when I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database from a servlet connection, a ClassNotFoundException for the PostgreSQL driver, with some details about servlet.
Class.forName("org.postgresql.driver");

DriverManager conn = Driver.getConnection(addr, user, pass);

I'm using Apache Tomcat (local server) for the server hosting.

I found the solution and my question answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/how-to-install-jdbc-driver-in-servlet-based-project-without-facing-java-lang-cla

That is not the name of the PostgreSQL driver, the correct name is org.postgresql.Driver (note the capital D). But, you don't need that line in the first place; as long as the PosgreSQL JDBC driver is on the classpath, it'll work (and if it isn't, that Class.forName won't magically fix things either). So:

remove the Class.forName line.

If it still does not work fix your classpath.



I tried that and I removed the Class.forName line but after that the servlet errors: there isn't any driver for the jdbc url. my classpath is correct too.

Then your classpath is not correct; the jar that contains the JDBC driver for postgres isn't on it.

I found my answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353141/how-to-install-jdbc-driver-in-servlet-based-project-without-facing-java-lang-cla

There are cases, especially in web applications, where using Class.forName is still necessary, e.g. with Tomcat (and probably most other application servers) when the driver is in WEB-INF/lib instead of the server's lib folder. Java's DriverManager only automatically loads drivers once, so if a driver is not on the classpath when drivers are loaded automatically, it will need to be loaded explicitly at a later time.
