# How to fix " java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" with BlueJ and Wampserver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wampserver, bluej

I am a new programmer with BlueJ I had to create a class called **`Connexion`** which connects to my MySQL database, but I get this error:

**`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`**

**My Code:**

```
import java.sql.* ;

public class Connexion{

  /**
  * Connect to MySQL and read the table "Etat", then 
  * print the contents of the first column.
  */
  public static void  test()
  {
        try
        {
              // Load the database driver
              Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;

              // Get a connection to the database
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(    

              "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OACA?user=root&password=" ) ;

              // Print all warnings
              for( SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings(); warn != null; warn = warn.getNextWarning() )
              {
                    System.out.println( "SQL Warning:" ) ;
                    System.out.println( "State  : " + warn.getSQLState()  ) ;
                    System.out.println( "Message: " + warn.getMessage()   ) ;
                    System.out.println( "Error  : " + warn.getErrorCode() ) ;
              }

              // Get a statement from the connection
              Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;

              // Execute the query
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Etat" ) ;

              // Loop through the result set
              while( rs.next() )
              System.out.println( rs.getString(1) ) ;

              // Close the result set, statement and the connection
              rs.close() ;
              stmt.close() ;
              conn.close() ;
        }
        catch( SQLException se )
        {
              System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

              // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
              while( se != null )
              {
                    System.out.println( "State  : " + se.getSQLState()  ) ;
                    System.out.println( "Message: " + se.getMessage()   ) ;
                    System.out.println( "Error  : " + se.getErrorCode() ) ;

                    se = se.getNextException() ;
              }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
              System.out.println( e ) ;
        }
  }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
   }
}
```

So how can I connect to my MySQL v5.6.17 database that is in my Wampserver. 
I think that I need a coonector.jar But I don't know which one that I would actually need.
Can you give your opinion please?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include the driver in the classpath.
If you're using maven, add the driver as a dependency in your pom.xml file

something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using maven, try the solution proposed in this question:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse)

Comment: I fixed it it was problem with connectors but in my code    System.out.println( rs.getString(1) ) ;
        System.out.println( rs.getString(2) ) ;
        System.out.println( rs.getString(3) ) ;
        System.out.println( rs.getString(4) ) ;
        System.out.println( rs.getString(5) ) ; when I run it it doesn't give me all the contents