# Error loading driver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Even After Adding JAR

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on my first JDBC web app and trying to get it to connect to my MySQL database.

The SQL service is running as far as I can tell since it's visible from the the processes tab in Task Manager. I've also added the jar to my build path and its clearly visible under Java Resources>src>Libraries>mysql-connector.jar.

However, I still get this error :

> Error  loading  driver:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

This is the only code left in my doGet method:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) 
{
    System.out.println("Error  loading  driver:  " + cnfe);
}
```

Comment: But does your deployed application also have the MySQL connector JAR?  By the way, I believe it is no longer necessary to use `Class.forName` to explicitly load the JDBC JAR.

Comment: So many dupe targets for this. Justin search better.

Comment: @Drew - nice gold badge in [tag:mysql], that was a grind for sure! you are dedicated my friend!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thx. A slow grind. Setting up servers then answering their question :p

Comment: @Drew did you see `Java Resources>src>Libraries>mysql-connector.jar`? Using this path means Justin use an IDE(I think it's eclipse).So it's a question about how to add jar to classpath in the used IDE. :)

Comment: Then http://stackoverflow.com/q/17484764

Comment: I searched for the better part of an hour and didn't find the solution, but I may have just missed it. What ended up working for me was moving the jar file to the WEB-INF lib folder in eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your jar is under classpath.
If you use eclipse, you can right click the jar and choose `build Path` > `add to build path`.
Maybe you should try using maven or other dependency managers.It's easier to use them than managing jar yourself.