# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, classloader, servletexception

I am trying to build a login-registration web app which essentially lets users register on a database and then allows them to log in. I have written all the code, and I am trying to connect my program to my database. Here is the error I receive:

```
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
```

I have added all the Postgres, Tomcat, and SQL connector/driver jar to my `classpath` and my `WEB-INF/lib` folders. I am not really sure what else to do. I have tried testing with another class and I am able to connect to my database. I have triple check my connection URL as well. What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Strange. This is usually due to missing jar in classpath. Can you please provide bit more detailed stacktrace?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your reply!                                                        
                                                                                                                   
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [login.submit.register.LoginRegister] in context with path [/RegistrationPage] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1257)

Comment: I have the postgres and mysql connectors jars - am I missing any?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse

Comment: I am using postgres, not mysql, so my link is "org.postgres.Driver", and I have already added the driver jars to the project. What else can I do?

Comment: `java.sql.Driver` is part of the JDK, seems like your Java installation is broken

Comment: NoClassDefFound indicates that the class was found but could not be initialised. Sounds like a URL or password problem, or the Tomcat server does not have access to the DB server.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this problem while running Jetpack compose desktop app,
consider adding this line into `build.gradle.kts`

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        // ..
        nativeDistributions {
            // ...
            modules("java.sql")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has nothing to do with Servlets, but I had the same problem with a module application that uses SQLite:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 14 more
```

A little puzzling at at first, but I finally figured it out.  I just had to add the *requires* statement for *java.sql* to the `module-info.java`:

```
module mymodule {
    ...
    requires sqlite.jdbc;
    requires java.sql;
}
```

(The *requires sqlite.jdbc* was already in there, added it above just for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin Compose Multiplatform this seems to fall in the category "It's a feature and not a bug". philoopher97 posted already the solution.

See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2668#issuecomment-1419178642) for a complete explanation including a hint on how to configure Proguard.