# How to export a java jar file with its database?

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file, deployment, export

I completed my very first project and i export it to a jar file. After that i made a text document and convert it into a bat file

Inside of the text document i put this

```
java -jar MyProject.jar

pause
```

but after executing the bat file i encountered an error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

So im currently stuck in the Login page. I feel like im missing something, what is it?

My program is running fine in my Eclipse IDE and its connected to the database successfully, but when i click the .bat file of my project it gives me an error why?, i can't figure out what is wrong and missing

im new to this please guide and help me

Comment: Can you tell me where are you trying to run your .jar file? Means if it is the same computer where it's developed?

Comment: im sorry i don't quite get what you mean, I just double click the .bat file (the .jar is inside of it) and then program is running through command prompt

Comment: Did you link the library containing the Database Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver? You may have not included it in your jar.

Comment: @xxx Ok. The error you're getting means your MySQL connectivity library is not included. There might be a chance you're not including the above mentioned library with your final build.

Comment: in the the library? oh no, my library only contains mysql-connector.  Would you send me a reference guide, or tell me how to do that?

Comment: Kindly check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722642/5082301). Might be of some help to you!