# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Java/Eclipse to connect to MySQL database but encountering the following error.

### Error Message:

> Unable to connect to databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

### Code:

```
<%
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB", "root", "password");
    if(! myCon.isClosed())
      out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server!");

    myCon.close();
  }catch(Exception ex){
      out.println("Unable to connect to database" + ex);
  }      
%>
```

I know that this question has  already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver) but still I am unable to sort this thing out.

### Environmental variables:

> JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
>
> CLASSPATH: .%JAVA_HOME%\lib;C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.29;

How can I can solve this issue?

Comment: As @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen said, the CLASSPATH generally won't apply in a web environment. Even if it did (in more classic environment), you'd need the exact jar name, not the name of the directory containing the jars.

Comment: @bruno see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html for instructions on how to use wildcards in the Classpath definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Eclipse project doesn't know where you have the drivers for the database.  You need to include them under the WEB-INF/lib directory so that they become part of the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Inside tomcat the external definitions do not apply.

Either deploy the driver jar with your application or add it to the extension library inside Tomcat.  I would use the first if Tomcat is not expected to help you with e.g. connection pools or similar

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eclipse then add MySQL jars in projects lib folder.

Comment: Thank you for all these answers. It worked after copying
mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar to WEB-INF/lib directory.

Is't there another way by adding a code statement that will reference the mySql connector jar? In a forum, they suggested to write the following:
        java -cp<path to jars>;. myclass

Where am I supposed to write this command?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked for me also for the error as 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Copied the sql connector jar file to lib folder of web-inf .

After copying this, the value from html to mysql database is sucessfully inserted
Thanks for the Help