# ClassNotFoundException 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, connector

I got this error when I use `Class.forName[...]`.
I used the JConnector MSI Installer (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) so I got no ZIP file to add to my build path or I don't know where the installer put it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Include the mysql.jar file in your build path.

Comment: add mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar in your classpath

Comment: You can get the file from here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjar.htm

Comment: I don't know where the installer put it. It didn't show a directory and immediatly closed after finishing the installation.

Comment: @Dyrdek Which id and server you are using?

Comment: I want to connect to a XAMPP MySQL Database. And the server is a Apache.

Comment: You can always just choose "other platforms" and download the zip version containing the jar. Its an odd choice of Oracle to only offer the msi download when you pick windows as the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert this:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

before getting the JDBC Connection.

Other option :

> 1: Download the mysql-connector-java.jar
>
> 2: You need to drop JAR in /WEB-INF/lib folder.
>
> 3: properties of project->build path->add JAR and selected the JAR
>   above.

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: Apache, and I'm using XAMPP if this is kind of helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I created the project as a Dynamic Web Project and follow your instructions with the /WEB/INF/lib and the build path ;) Works!