# Setup JDBC driver in Eclipse java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have problem with setting up jdbc driver. I have searched for solution and tried many things.

Firstly, I tried to put my driver .jar file into WebContent/WEB-INF, 
got error with Abandoned connection cleanup thread, then I tried to put my .jar file into Library/Tomcat/Lib, but got error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I also tried to put it in my project folder directory and add through build path. The same problem.

What else can I try? What can be the problem? Or what am I doing wrong? Please, help.

Comment: Did you try adding the mysql connector to build path as an external jar?

Comment: @Perdomoff, yes, same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver.. this forum will help you

Comment: I added picture in my answer which will show you how to add mysql connector jar in ur classpath

Comment: what have you tried? how are you trying to use the mysql jdbc driver? post  the code that's causing the CNFE

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add MySQL connector jar in your class path, add external jar as shown in my picture [image]