# How should I connect database in mysql workbench with my web application?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I created a web application in eclipse but I cannot connect to the schema I created in the sql workbench. So can anyone tell me in detail what are the things I did was wrong.

Here is my code for connection:-

```
   try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","root");  

    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    stmt.executeQuery("Insert into Regsitered_users(Name,Pass,email)" + "values('"+name+"','"+pass+"','"+email+"')");
}
```

But this error is generated:-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.arithmatic.pkg.Reg.doPost(Reg.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download `mysql-jdbc` jar , you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm) and add it in your `bin` folder, if you are using eclipse, restart `tomcat` server , and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` If you use build tool like Maven you have to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise you have to add external jar to your project. You can download it from here: https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Yes I have downloaded that jar file and added in the workspace and also I built a path for that. Still I am getting that error. @PetarPetrov

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver Read this.