# HTML page is not connecting to database

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

I am asking for a user input in the index.jsp and I take that input to a different search.jsp where I search the database with given query.  However, it's not connecting to database.  Can someone please help me.

Here is my code in **index.jsp** that asks for user input

```
<form method="searchh" action="search.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>    
           <td><b class="accent">Enter College Name: </b> &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="college" STYLE="color: #f4d442; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #72A4D2;" size="10" maxlength="30"></td>
           <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Search Your College" <a href="#submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-satact" role="button"></a>></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here is my code in **search.jsp**.  The database name/url/id/password is all entered correctly.  I used the same code for different search file.  It works perfectly in that file.  However, it doesn't connect to database in this .jsp file. Here is my code for search.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!--Import some libraries that have classes that we need -->
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%
    try {

    //Create a connection string
    String url = "my_data_base_link";
    //Load JDBC driver - the interface standardizing the connection procedure. Look at WEB-INF\lib for a mysql connector jar file, otherwise it fails.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //Create a connection to your DB
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");

    //Create a SQL statement
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String college = request.getParameter("college");

    String str = "SELECT College, TUITIONFEE_IN, State FROM my_project1.all WHERE College LIKE " + "'" + college + "%'";

    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(str);
    con.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    out.print("insert failed");
}
```

It prints out insert fail in the catch part of try and catch.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to print actual exception to see where error occurred.

Comment: @Aleksandar thank you it's a class not found error.  Any idea how whould i fix that?

Comment: well, you didn't mention class name for ClassNotFound exception, but if it's about the driver, try with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you.  I figured it out.  It was missing the mysql-connecter jar file.  I added that from project properties ->buildpath -> add external jar (to bin folder under webINF->lib)

link for mysql connector http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html