# i got error in java jdbc mysql in terminal(mac) so how to fix this error?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am recently run java program in terminal in mac. I write one jdbc with mysql program, i think whole program is write but it throws error that i mentioned in output. so please help me to solve this error and also tell me at which place should i place the mysql connector.

program code is as follow,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
class DBConnectio
{
int id;
String name,pass;
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
void getData()
{
    System.out.println("Enter id:");
    id=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter username:");
    name=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Password:");
    pass=sc.next();

}
DBConnectio()throws Exception
{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadata",
    "root","root");
    st = con.createStatement(); 

}
void menu()throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("1.Insert");
    System.out.println("2.Update");
    System.out.println("3.Delete");
    System.out.println("Enter choice:");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    switch(n)
    {
        case 1: insert(); break;
        case 2: update(); break;
        case 3: delete(); break;
        default: System.out.println("Wrong choice");
    }
 }
    void insert()throws Exception
    {
        getData();
        String q="insert into student values 
        ("+id+",'"+name+"','"+pass+"')";
        int n=st.executeUpdate(q);
        System.out.println(n+ "rows inserted...");
    }
    void update()throws Exception
    {
        getData();
        String q="update student set uname='"+name+"',pass='"+pass+"' 
        where id="+id+" ";
        int n=st.executeUpdate(q);
        if(n==0)
        {
            System.out.println("no record found..");
        }
        else
         {
            System.out.println(n+ "rows updated...");   
        }
    }
    void delete()throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        id=sc.nextInt();
        String q="delete from student where id="+id;
        int n=st.executeUpdate(q);
        if(n==0)
        {
            System.out.println("no record found..");
        }
        else
         {
            System.out.println(n+ "rows deleted...");   
        }
    }

   }

class demo
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
    DBConnectio z=new DBConnectio();
    z.menu();

}
}
```

i got output like this,

```
vishals-MacBook-Pro:desktop vishalbarad$ javac demo.java
vishals-MacBook-Pro:desktop vishalbarad$ java demo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at DBConnectio.<init>(demo.java:24)
at demo.main(demo.java:87)
```

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: You haven't specified a class path with the driver on the command line. Specifically check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/466862), point 2

Comment: But how to specify a class path in terminal not command line?

Comment: Specifically check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/466862), point 2

Comment: okay thank you i got the answer..